# Filezilla If statements

Tags: batch-file, ftp, filezilla

In the batch file segment I've posted I have an issue where I need to use filezilla and the command line to ensure that a scheduled script hasn't lost it's connection.  My attempt was to use an if statement to verify the presence of a folder on the remote server, with the goal in mind that if there was no connection the file wouldn't be found and the program would exit immediately.  The current batch file doesn't do this it instead continues on and may ultimately delete files whether or not they've been fixed.  Any advice on both this file or an alternative method to accomplish the same thing would be greatly appreciated.

```
open xx.xx.xx.xx<br>
xxxxxxxx<br>
xxxxxxxx<br>
cd xxxxx<br>
! if exist xx.xx.xx.xx/xxxxxx/ (<br>
    mput *.mp4<br> 
)
! if not exist xx.xx.xx.xx/xxxxxxx (<br>
    close<br> 
)

! del *.mp4<br>
quit<br>
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

In a batch command:

```
ping -n 1 ftp.server.com >nul || echo server is not responding
```